# SSIS XML root attributes missing

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd, bids

I have an XML source.. I can not seem to get the root attributes to be available.  I have three other sections (elements) which all show as available.. it odes not seem to provide the root attributes.  Has anyone seen this issue?
After selecting the XML source file and xsd.. I go to columns.. the "output name" drop down has three of the four sections.. the root section is not there.. 
How do I get at those root attribs?
I tried to generate XSD from within BIDS.  I tried to build a cleaner one with Trang  no difference in outputs available..

ANY suggestions?

-Ken

Comment: Are you doing this in a Data Flow task or are you talking about using the XML Task? Can you post samples of the XML and XSD you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915852/generate-nested-types-instead-of-global-types-with-xsd-exe/7971818#7971818); I expect it to work in your case as well.